# PHP - RegEx - Find words which begins and ends equally

Tags: php, regex

I try to find hashtags in

```
some words
#one #two
#three#four#five
```

by such an expression

```
(#.*?)(\s|#|$)
```

But can't find #four

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all hashtags with this simple regex where there is absolutely no overlapping problem as you are facing in your current regex,

```
#\w+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YcBzPI/1)

Also, if you think your hashtag word can contain some more characters like `-` or or `.` You can modify your character set like this `[\w.-]`

[Demo for enhanced character set](https://regex101.com/r/YcBzPI/2)

Here is a sample php code,

```
$str = "#one #two \n#three#four#five";
preg_match_all('/#\w+/s', $str, $matches);
for ($i=0;$i<count($matches[0]);$i++) {
    echo $matches[0][$i] . "\n";
}
```

This gives following output listing all hashtags found,

```
#one
#two
#three
#four
#five
```

Comment: Thanks for advice! For my purpose this #[^\s#]+ is better.